# React isn't recognizing object within my state

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

So i'm building a component in react that is fetching data from an API, and I'm getting a build error in browser. it's telling me that down in the render section, It's not recognizing "students". But i've looked at how the JSON data from the API is structured, and it follows that. I set the state to the data of the JSON, yet when I render it doesn't recognize students? Any tips? thank you so much!

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default class FetchRandomUser extends React.Component {
  state = {
    students: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("...")
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ students: data})
        console.log(this.state)
      })
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <ul>
        { students.map(student => 
        <li key={student.id}>
          {student.city}
          </li>
          ) 
        }
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: It's `this.state.students.map(...)`. Also, an axios call returns a `response`  object, and you need to access `response.data` for the actual server data. You can use `.then(({data}) => ...` to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access students from `state` property of the component,

```js
 render(){
    const {students} = this.state;
    return (
      <ul>
        { students.map(student => 
        <li key={student.id}>
          {student.city}
          </li>
          ) 
        }
      </ul>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending @majdsalloum

setState is async so if you immediately console.log state it won't reflect in your state students variable

Comment: True but not an answer to OPs question or part of the problem.

Answer (score -1):

try with your state in a constructor like

```
constructor(props) { super(props); this.state = { students: []}; }
```

add `this.state` in front of your students variables.

also, you can view your axios response by just using

```
console.log(data)
```